# Maintain Precedence of logical expression when GCC is optimized for fast

Tags: gcc, optimization, task, freertos, notify

I have a FreeRTOS task that uses task notification to signal between a calling function and the task itself. However the task can also be "unblocked" by a flag dataWaiting.

```
/* Make this function not optimized to maintain precedence of logical operation */
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("O0")

void printTask(void * argument)
{
  uart1Busy = false;

  int kItr;
  char chr[1];

  while(1)
  {
    /* If data is waiting then dive straight in, otherwise wait for a notification
     * from the printfdma function.
     */
    if((dataWaiting || ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY)))
    {
        dataWaiting = false;
```

If I allow the Ofast optimization the compiler reorders the *if* statement such that the function never "unblocks"  To fix this I did a pragma push "O0 to prevent optimization, however this has to be applied across the whole task.

Does anyone know how you can "force" the order of the logical expression to be honored with optimization made Ofast?

Comment: Here is a rule of thumb for you: if turning optimizations on breaks your code, you probably have undefined behavior in your program.

Reordering the if statement would change the behaviour, because of short-circuiting rules. The optimizer is not allowed to do that.

Please post the full code, including the declaration of `dataWaiting`.

Comment: As soon as you said you wanted to see the declaration of the dataWaiting variable I knew it was all over: I had bool dataWaiting; instead of volatile bool dataWaiting. It now works with Ofast.